# How to transfer the pk of one model to another

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models task and subtask.
First, a user is supposed to create a task, then the user can create subtasks for the previously created task.

In the model for subtask, I created a foreignkey for task.

The easy way would be to get task name(or id) front the user while making a new subtask to create the link between the two.

But I want to do it the following way.

User creates a task and is redirected to a page where all tasks are listed. The user selects a certain task and then is sent to a page that shows all subtasks for the selected task.
There is a link to create a new subtask on this page and when the user uses this link, a new subtask can be created which automatically gets associated with the selected task.

Forgive me if this question is trivial.
Thanks in advance!!!

EDIT: as Daniel said 
I added this in html
`<a href="{% url 'subtask-create' object.id %}">Create a subtask</a>`

added this in urls.py
`path('task/user/subtask/new/<int:pk>', views.SubtaskCreateView.as_view(), name='subtask-create')`

This displays the task primary key in url.

the view function for subtask creation is:

```
class SubtaskCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Subtask
    form_class = subtaskCreateForm
```

Now how do i capture the task primary key and fit in the foreign key field for Subtask.
I believe this would have been easier if I used function based views.

Comment: The simplest way would probably be to include the task ID in the create subtask URL.

Answer (score 0):

added post function in the CreateView.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = kwargs.get('pk')
        form = SubtaskCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('forms valid')
            subtask = form.save(commit=False)
            subtask.task = task.objects.get(id = pk)
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
        print('form invalid')
        return render(request, 'users/subtask_form.html', {'form':form})
```